# Read-only generic collection interfaces

Tags: c#, collections

Ok I have been trying to find the best way to do read-only generic collection interfaces and this is what I came up with:

```
public delegate Boolean EnumerateItemsDelegate<ItemType>(ItemType item);
public delegate Boolean EnumerateItemsDelegate(Object item);

public interface IReadOnlyObjectCollection<out ItemType>
{
    Boolean ContainsItem(Object item);
    Array CopyToArray();
    void EnumerateItems(EnumerateItemsDelegate enumerateItemsDelegate);

    UInt32 Count { get; }
    UInt32 Capacity { get; }
}

public interface IReadOnlyCollection<ItemType> : IReadOnlyObjectCollection<ItemType>
{
    Boolean ContainsItem(ItemType item);
    Array<ItemType> CopyToArray();
    void EnumerateItems(EnumerateItemsDelegate<ItemType> enumerateItemsDelegate);

    UInt32 Count { get; }
    UInt32 Capacity { get; }
}
```

This is intended to sidestep the big problem with the Microsoft collection interfaces... Not being able to assign a derived read-only collection to a base one.

```
IReadOnlyObjectCollection<String> s;
IReadOnlyObjectCollection<Object> o = s;
```

The interfaces aren't ideal obviously since you still have to use 'Object' instead of the actual type but I think this is as close as you can get without having compile-time only generics.  I would definitely appreciate if you guys see any huge problems or drawbacks with this...

Comment: At first glance, I'd consider having them at least implement `IEnumerable<ItemType>` so you can do most of the work you normally would with a collection (foreach, linq) and wouldn't have to bother with the `EnumerateItems` method.

Comment: Also, have you considered leveraging the `System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection`? You might not be able to treat a `ReadOnlyCollection<string>` as a `ReadOnlyCollection<object>`, but you can treat it as an `IEnumerable<object>` at least. If you can get by with that, maybe it will be easier than rolling your own.

Comment: Well EnumerateItems can be used with an anonymous lambda method for pretty easy use.  Not quite as easy as foreach though...  I gave up with the default collections when I needed IObserveOnlyCollection<> and had to roll a huge complex collection to do it right.